# Adding variable to a sql statement isn't working

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I want to add variables to my table in sql (android) but this is not working

```
articlesDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO articles VALUES(" + theId + "," + title + "," + url +  ")");
```

Comment: String should be `'your title'`

Comment: You should probably be using statement parameters.

Answer (score 0):

This is how it worked

```
articlesDatabase.execSQL("INSERT INTO articles Values (" + theId + ", '" + title + "', '" + url + "');");
```